# tkinter: Set option command for Entry after declared it

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I need to declare the option command for an entry after declare it, here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from utils import *
import re

def main():
    #create window
    window=tk.Tk()

    #set window size, window title and window icon
    window.geometry("600x600")
    window.title("Calculator")
    window.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file="icon.png"))

    #set title
    title = tk.Label(window, text="Calculator", font=("Ubuntu", 25), anchor=tk.CENTER,  pady=10)
    title.pack()

    #set input box
    entry = tk.Entry(window) 
    entry["command"] = lambda: checkEntry(entry) # issues start here
    entry.pack()




    #show window
    window.mainloop()

def checkEntry(entry: tk.Entry):
    char = entry.get()[-1]
    allowed = ["(", ")", "+", "*", ",", "-", "/"]
    regex = re.match("[0-9]", char)

    if regex is None and char not in allowed:
        text = entry.get()
        entry.insert(0, text[:-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the full error I got:

```
/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/ubuntu/programmi/calculator-gui/calculator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/programmi/calculator-gui/calculator.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/programmi/calculator-gui/calculator.py", line 20, in main
    entry["command"] = lambda: checkEntry(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1657, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-command"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there another way to pass the command option after declared it? Because I need to pass the entry in the function parameter set in the command

Comment: The error is because [`Entry`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry.html) widgets don't have a `command` option — that's not how they work.

Comment: I saw here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/tk_entry.htm/ Entry has that

Comment: The error you're getting indicates otherwise.

Comment: does validatecommand do the same?

Comment: Things aren't that simple. Think about it — what would trigger such as callback on a widget like this? Read the [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry.html) about `Entry` widgets I linked to in my original comment. Note the part about [Adding validation to an `Entry` widget](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html).

Comment: Good to hear — now you can post an answer to your own question (which is allowed here).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a working solution. You should use the `validatecommand`, you can find the detailed documentation of it: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html

I have written many comments in the code for the better understanding and why I did the things.

**Complete code:**

```
import tkinter as tk


def main():
    # create window
    window = tk.Tk()

    # set window size, window title and window icon
    window.geometry("600x600")
    window.title("Calculator")

    # set title
    title = tk.Label(window, text="Calculator", font=("Ubuntu", 25), anchor=tk.CENTER, pady=10)
    title.pack()

    # set input box
    entry = tk.Entry(window, validate="key")
    entry['validatecommand'] = (entry.register(checkEntry), '%P')
    entry.pack()
    # show window

    window.mainloop()


def checkEntry(val):
    # This if is needed when you remove the complete Entry content.
    if not val:
        return True
    allowed = ["(", ")", "+", "*", ",", "-", "/"]

    # We want to check only the last character of Entry.
    last_char = val[-1]

    # You can use the "isdigit()" to check if character is number instead of RegEx.
    if not last_char.isdigit() and last_char not in allowed:
        # The value is not allowed if it's not number or not a character in list.
        print("Not allowed character: {}".format(last_char))
        return False
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Not allowed character: =
Not allowed character: d
Not allowed character: f
Not allowed character: a
Not allowed character: a
Not allowed character: d
```

**GUI:**

[image: Calculator GUI]